# Dictionary comprehension with Q

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-3.2

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
criteria = {'description': 'tt', 'hostname': '2'}
filters = Q()
{filters.add(Q(**{k+'__icontains': v}), Q.AND) for k,v in criteria.items()}
```

I can't figure out how to avoid doubling the outcome:

```
{<Q: (AND: ('description__icontains', 'tt'), ('hostname__icontains', '2'))>,
 <Q: (AND: ('description__icontains', 'tt'), ('hostname__icontains', '2'))>}
```

I understand I should shift `Q.AND` somewhere, shouldn't I?

Comment: Are you sure the outcome is doubled, and you're not just seeing the same Q object, `filters`, printed twice? Can you show us what `str(filters)` looks like after this code?

Comment: That was the right track. `str(filters)` gives:
`(AND: ('description__icontains', 'tt'), ('hostname__icontains', '2'))`
Thanks Wander!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're inspecting the resulting `set` from the set comprehension, which lists the same `Q` object (`filters`) twice, after it's been modified. That's actually not a problem - you don't use that resulting set anywhere - but it does look a bit surprising.

As an alternative, it should be possible to pass all the `kwargs` you want to `Q()` in one go:

```
criteria = {'description': 'tt', 'hostname': '2'}
filters = Q(**{k + '__icontains': v for k, v in criteria.items()})
```

That removes the need for the set comprehension.